# Number circled near tab title, like WhatsApp (Android)

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am developing an application for Android that use TabLayout.
I'm trying to put near the title of one of the tabs, a circled number, as WhatsApp for unread chats tab.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can just add a second TextView and modify the background drawable to make it look like that. Alternatively, you can create a custom view which does this

Comment: How can I add a second TextView to the title?